# Register component based on parameter name on requestor in windsor

Tags: components, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have this interface for using AutoMapper:

```cs
public interface IMapper
{
    object Map(object source, Type sourceType, Type destinationType);
}
```

Then for each type of data, I have a different mapper class , for example:

```cs
 public class UserMapper : IMapper
{
    static UserMapper()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<UserViewModel, User>();
    }

    public object Map(object source, Type sourceType, Type destinationType)
    {
        return Mapper.Map(source, sourceType, destinationType);
    }
}
```

Then I have IMapper as one of the parametter in my controller class like this:

```cs
public UsersController(IUsersRepository repo, IMapper userMapper)
{....}
```

I am using Windsor as the IOC for my application and the problem is that I want to register the components, so that when running in UsersController , it use the UserMapper class and if running on ProductsController it will use my ProductMapper class.

My registration code looks something along the line of this:

```cs
container.Register(
    Component.For<IMapper>()
             .ImplementedBy<UsersMapper>()
             .Named("usersMapper"),
    Component.For<IMapper>()
             .ImplementedBy<ProductsMapper>()
             .Named("productsMapper"),
    Component.For<ProductController>()
             .ServiceOverrides(ServiceOverride.ForKey("usersMapper").Eq("productsMapper"))
)
```

I have done my homework on google and stackoverflow, and i know that I need to use ServicesOverride but I am still stuck on this, could anyone give me a hand please?

Thanks

Comment: something along the line of this: container.Register(
    Component.For<IMyMapper>()
        .ImplementedBy<UsersMapper>()
        .Named("usersMapper"),
    Component.For<IMapper>()
        .ImplementedBy<ProductsMapper>()
        .Named("productsMapper"),
 
    Component.For<ProductController>()
        .ServiceOverrides(ServiceOverride.ForKey("usersMapper").Eq("productsMapper"))
);

Comment: sorry, my bad, should be IMapper not IMyMapper, updated now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While svick's solution looks correct to me (I haven't attempted to compile it, though), this scenario is an excellent case for **convention-based configuration**.

Let's introduce this convention: *Each consumer of IMapper will signal the intended role of the mapper by its name. By default, that name will be matched with a type of the same name - only with different casing.*

So, constructor parameters could be mapped like this:

- userMapper -> UserMapper
- productMapper -> ProductMapper

In Castle Windsor, such a configuration might look like this:

```cs
container.Register(Classes
    .FromThisAssembly()
    .Pick()
    .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
    .WithServiceSelf());

container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(
    new MapperConvention(container.Kernel));
```

And the Sub Resolver (where the magic really happens) looks like this:

```cs
public class MapperConvention : ISubDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IKernel kernel;

    public MapperConvention(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    public bool CanResolve(CreationContext context,
        ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver,
        ComponentModel model,
        DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        return typeof(IMapper).IsAssignableFrom(dependency.TargetType);
    }

    public object Resolve(CreationContext context,
        ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver,
        ComponentModel model,
        DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        var representativeMapperType = typeof(UserMapper);
        var concreteMapperType = representativeMapperType.Assembly
            .GetExportedTypes()
            .Where(t => 
                t.Name.Equals(dependency.DependencyKey,
                    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            .Single();
        return this.kernel.Resolve(concreteMapperType);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works well for me, brilliant solution, thanks a lot Mark.

Answer (score 7):

This registration works for me:

```cs
container.Register(
    Component.For<IMapper>()
        .ImplementedBy<UserMapper>()
        .Named("userMapper"),
    Component.For<IMapper>()
        .ImplementedBy<ProductMapper>()
        .Named("productMapper"),
    Component.For<UsersController>()
        .ServiceOverrides(ServiceOverride.ForKey<IMapper>().Eq("userMapper")),
    Component.For<ProductsController>()
        .ServiceOverrides(ServiceOverride.ForKey<IMapper>().Eq("productMapper"))
    );
```

Comment: thanks , but I have tried it before and again now but This registration doesn't work for me, it saying my controller component class is already registered

Comment: @tuanvt what is the exact error? Maybe you register something twice.

Comment: hi svick ,here is the error:Component DataTracking.Web.Controllers.UsersController could not be registered. There is already a component with that name. Did you want to modify the existing component instead? If not, make sure you specify a unique name.

Comment: it is probably because, in my controller installer, I already have this:   container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                                .BasedOn<IController>()
                                .LifestyleTransient());