# Castle Windsor Register Component by Convention

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I want to implement auto-registration for my repositories, which follow this convention:

- Repositories implement `IRepository`
- There is an abstract class which implements `IRepository`, for example: `UserRepository`
- The actual implementation ends in the name of this abstract class, for instance: `EntityFrameworkUserRepository`

I want to inject dependencies using castle into my controllers.

```
public LinkService(LinkRepository linkRepository)
{
    if (linkRepository == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("linkRepository");
    }
    this.linkRepository = linkRepository;
}
```

How can I map "components which implement `IRepository`" to "implementations which end with the same name as the component"

```
container.Register(Component.For<LinkRepository>().ImplementedBy<EntityFrameworkLinkRepository>())
```

something like this, only auto-registering, so I don't have to add all repositories here manually each time I create a new one

Comment: possible duplicate of [Register component based on parameter name on requestor in windsor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339840/register-component-based-on-parameter-name-on-requestor-in-windsor)

Comment: I think it's a good idea to use conventions for setting up the container. But you should think about why you need the repository to hide your ORM. Ayende has written a lot about this. One of the posts: http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might do it:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(
    AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<EntityFrameworkLinkRepository>()
        .BasedOn<IRepository>()
        .WithService.Select((type, types) => type.BaseType != null && type.Name.EndsWith(type.BaseType.Name)
                                                    ? new[] {type.BaseType}
                                                    : Enumerable.Empty<Type>()));
```

Comment: Did it like this but replacing your `.Where` with `.BasedOn<IRepository>()`