# Dependency on Log4Net Logger and Retrieve Logger by Caller Type using Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, log4net

I have a thin wrapper around `log4net` and I am trying to use the type of the calling class to get a logger from `log4net.LogManager` by using `Castle.Windsor`.

```
public class Foo: IFoo
{
    private readonly ICommonLog _logger;

    public Foo(ICommonLog logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void FooBar()
    {
        _logger.Info("Enter FooBar Method");
    }
}

public class CommonLog : ICommonLog
{
    private readonly log4net.ILog _logger;

    public CommonLog(Type loggerType)
    {
        _logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(loggerType); 
    }

    public void Info(string message)
    {         
        _logger.Info(message.Cleanse());
    }

    // ...
}
```

I have tried this registration in `Castle.Windsor` (2.5.1) and I am able to get the correct logger for `Foo`. Am I mis-using dynamic parameters for this scenario? Is there a more elegant solution?

```
container.Register(Component.For<ICommonLog>().ImplementedBy(typeof(CommonLog)).
   LifeStyle.Transient);
container.Register(Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy(typeof(Foo)).
   LifeStyle.Transient.DynamicParameters(
       (k, d) =>
       {
          var component = k.Resolve<ICommonLog>(new {loggerType = typeof (Foo)});
          d["logger"] = component;
          return r =>
          {
              if (component != null)
              {
                  r.ReleaseComponent(component);
              }
          };
       })
  );
```

Edit: I've updated the solution using `ISubDependencyResolver`:

```
public class LoggerResolver : ISubDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IKernel kernel;

    public LoggerResolver(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    public bool CanResolve(CreationContext context,
                           ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver,
                           ComponentModel model,
                           DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        return dependency.TargetType == typeof (ICommonLog);
    }

    public object Resolve(CreationContext context,
                          ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver,
                          ComponentModel model,
                          DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        if (CanResolve(context, contextHandlerResolver, model, dependency))
        {
            return kernel.Resolve<ICommonLog>(new {loggerType = model.Implementation});
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Registration:

```
container.Register(Component.For<ICommonLog>().ImplementedBy(typeof(CommonLog))
    .LifeStyle.Transient);
container.Register(Component.For<IFoo().ImplementedBy(typeof(Foo))
    .LifeStyle.Transient);
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new LoggerResolver(container.Kernel));
```

Comment: Why not just use the logging facility?

Comment: You could use a convention-based approach. Here's a similar question (and answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339840/register-component-based-on-parameter-name-on-requestor-in-windsor

Comment: @MauricioScheffer thanks, I took a look at that before and may just adopt that without re-inventing the wheel here...

Comment: @MarkSeemann Thanks for the link. I couldn't see a convention here but used your example for the `ISubDependencyResolver` approach.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to register CommonLog. Your sub dependency resolver can new one up for you.

```
container.Register(Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<Foo>().LifeStyle.Transient);
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new LoggerResolver(container.Kernel));

public class LoggerResolver : ISubDependencyResolver
{
    ...

    public object Resolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        //No need to can resolve, Windsor will do this for you

        return new CommonLog(model.Implementation);
    }
}
```

EDIT Example of a logger provider

```
container.Register(Component.For<ILoggerProvider>().ImplementedBy<Log4NetLoggerProvider >().LifeStyle.Transient);

public interface ICommonLoggerProvider
{
    ICommonLog GetLogger( Type type );
}

public class Log4NetLoggerProvider : ICommonLoggerProvider
{
    public ICommonLog GetLogger(Type type)
    {
        return new Log4NetLogger(type);
    }
}

public class LoggerResolver : ISubDependencyResolver
{
    ...
    public object Resolve( CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, Castle.Core.ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency )
    {
        return kernel.Resolve<ICommonLoggerProvider>().GetLogger( model.Implementation );
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but what if I want to swap out implementation of `ICommonLog`? Lastly, `ComponentModel` doesn't expose the `TargetType` property.

Comment: @Luke Hutton - My bad, just had a look at my implementation and you were using the right property and I have updated the code. If you want to be able to swap out the logger you can introduce the concept of a provider / factory which you do register in windsor. I have updated the code to show what I have done but using your types.