# How to extend Castle Windsor LoggingFacility/ILogger

Tags: castle-windsor, log4net

I've been using log4net and the Castle Windsor LoggingFacility to inject an ILogger instance into classes where I need logging. The logger is registered like so:-

```
container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseLog4Net());
```

and in classes needing logging I create the following property that Windsor injects into:

```
public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
```

It's all working fine but I would like to somehow extend this logging to allow me to trace method entry and exit. Before Castle Windsor, I would have written a wrapper around log4net and added methods such as TraceEnter() and TraceExit(). These would get the current method name from the StackTrace class and do a *Log.Debug("Entered method Foo");*

I'm not sure the best way to extend the Castle Windsor logging stuff to achieve this. Any ideas?

**Edit:**

I've now created my own custom logger factory (inherits from Log4netFactory) and custom logger (inherits from Log4netLogger, and contains my Trace... methods), then register it with Windsor like so:-

```
container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.LogUsing<CustomLoggerFactory>());
```

Unfortunately I still have to expose a public property of type ILogger in my classes otherwise Windsor won't inject the logger. I can cast this to my custom logger but it's not very elegant:

```
(Logger as CustomLog4NetLogger).TraceEnter();
```

Comment: Eventually found the solution elsewhere on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509115/dependency-on-log4net-logger-and-retrieve-logger-by-caller-type-using-castle-win